# GeoServer and Oracle 12c

Tags: geoserver, oracle-dbms

In GeoServer (2.13.1) I'm trying to connect to Oracle DB 11g and 12c  and  connecting successfully both.  But in 12c I couldn't see my tables and can't add layer.

There isn't any error message or somethng like it.

Is there any way to reach them or how can i solve it.

-- Solved--

Oracle DB 12c has ojdbc8 driver in library file path  but GeoServer is tested and working correctly  with ojdbc7. With ojdbc8  successfully  connected and listed 11g tables but for 12c just connected to database, didnt list tables who in databese. Changing ojdbc8 to ojdbc7 connected and listed tables from 11g and 12c.

Comment: which JDBC driver did you add to GeoServer?

Comment: in geoserver lib i added  ojdbc8

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are using a too new driver, the documentation suggests that you use `ojdbc7.jar` and there is a good chance no one has tested out the latest `ojdbc8.jar` yet.

As Oracle is a proprietary database it tends not to attract volunteer support (which is how most of GeoServer is built). If the use of Oracle is important to you then I recommend you consider a [commercial support](http://geoserver.org/support/) contract, or switch to PostGIS which is well supported by the community.